# How to call LinkedServer tables in sqlserver from SSAS

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008

I have created linked server in MSSQL.

Next i will try to create a cube in SSAS,

when i create **Data Source View** in SSAS that MSSQL not showing linked server name.

Is it possible to access linked server tables from SSAS?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a linked server? Are the tables for your cube in different databases on different servers? If they are, have you tried creating a view in your primary server that uses the linked servers, then have these views in your SSAS Cube DSV?

Also, do look into data warehousing, it will probably be faster to process if you gather all the data you want in the cube into a single database first. If you have large databases this may be essential.